# Google Drive API でファイルをアップロードする際、Invalid Credentials エラーが出る

Tags: php, google-drive-sdk

Google Drive APIを使用したファイルをアップロードするPHPプログラムをcronで毎日稼働させています。
その中で下記エラーが発生しました。

```
Error Message: Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

内容自体は下記認証エラーだと思うのですが
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors?hl=ja#resolve_a_401_error_invalid_credentials

不可解なのは、常に上記エラーが出ているわけではなく、とある1日の一部プログラムのみ発生した点です。
該当プログラムは、毎日指定時間に合計25回ほど実行されているのですが、
4月より毎日稼働しているにも関わらず、とある日の一部稼働のみ（25回中9回）に発生しました。

認証ファイルやプログラム内容は変えていません。
認証エラーだとすると全ての日の全ての実行で発生すると思うのですが・・・。

Drive APIは下記を通じて使用しています。
google-api-php-client--PHP7.4
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases

PHPプログラム自体はごくシンプルなものです。

＜その他調査したこと＞
・毎朝8時前に実行していますが、エラー発生時刻にはとくに規則性は見当たりません。
・トークンは失効していません。
・Google DriveやDrive API自体の障害は報告されていません。
・cronを実行しているサーバーでも該当日の障害はありませんでした。

他に確認すべきことや試してみると良いことなどあればアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Status code 401は使用したアクセストークンが無効であることを示していると思われます。`トークンは失効していません。`は残念ながら理解できませんが、この場合、例えば、同様のエラーが発生した際は、再度アクセストークンを取得しなおしてからリクエストを行うのはいかがでしょうか。再リクエストの前には少しインターバルを設けるのも良いかもしれません。また、最大リトライ数は設定しておいたほうが良いと思われます。別のアプローチとして、エンドポイント`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=###`を使って最初にアクセストークンが有効かどうかを確認するのもありかもしれません。ただ、状況を再現することができないため、これらが直接の解決策になりうるかどうかはわかりません。このため、コメントとして提案させていただきました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

「トークンは失効していません。」については、
・GoogleCloudPlatform上でサービスアカウントのキーの有効期限が10000/01/01であること
・ほぼ同時刻に実行している同認証情報の同プログラムではエラーが起きていないものもあること
・他の日に実行している同認証情報の同プログラムではエラーが起きていないこと
から「失効していない」と判断しております。

おっしゃるとおり再現ができないので、ご提案いただいたリトライやトークン確認も検討したいと思います。
ありがとうございます。